# fstab bind inconsistency - Is a link a better option?

Tags: mount, fstab, kubuntu

When binding two folders together as configured in `/etc/fstab`;

```
#folder-with-old-data       new-empty-folder     fs   option  flags
/home/user1/Mydata/Pictures /home/user1/Pictures none bind    0 0
```

The "old" folder `Pictures` with existing data is located in a partition mounted in `Mydata`.  I wish for the folders and files within it to appear as folders and files in the "new" standard location of `/home/user1/Pictures`

In doing this, I want the existing data in the old folder to be accessible in the standard `/home/user1/Pictures` location.

When the folders are bound, all seems in order, **except** that when a new file is created in `/home/user1/Pictures` **, it does not appear** in the bind (bound) `/home/user1/Mydata/Pictures` folder!  Also, if the two folders are then un-bound with `umount`, the previously newly created  file in `/home/user1/Picture` folder **is lost in both folders!**

The reverse – that is files created in `/home/user1/Mydata/Pictures` – creates duplicates in `/home/user1/Pictures` which are retained in both locations after `umount`.... as expected.

If the two folders are rebound, the new file previously created in `/home/user1/Pictures` is visible again.

Q1. `bind` is too mature for this to be a bug, so what am I doing wrong?

Q2. Would it be more elegant to use `ln -s`.  I presume I then have the issue of modifying `/etc/init.d/rc2.d` to include a start up script which is less visible when it comes time to update, or rearrange drives etc.

System: Kubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

> When the folders are bound, all seems in order, except that when a new file is created in `/home/user1/Pictures` it does not appear in the bind (bound) `/home/user1/Mydata/Pictures` folder!

This could happen if some application already has `/home/user1/Pictures` as its current directory when fstab is read. It could also happen if you use ecryptfs to encrypt your home directory, as the mount point (given when `fstab` is read) is the one in the ciphertext hierarchy, not in the decrypted hierarchy.

I don't understand why you aren't using a symbolic link, nor why `/etc/init.d/rc2.d` is relevant.

Comment: Solved.
Your suggestion was correct.  When testing I had applications open in the subject folder.  No encryption was involved.

A symbolic link would work, but to have the link reestablished at every boot would require having a script somewhere, eg `/etc/init.d/rc2.d`

Thanks - help appreciated.

Comment: @PeterMac What do you mean by "have the link reestablished”? Is this an in-memory filesystem?

Comment: thanks.  I will need to play some more with links.  But I was unsuccessful the first time.